Quarkus build requires docker to be started in spite of Jib-presense
I'm pretty confused, trying to understand the logic how Quarkus container build works.
So what I do have:

Qaurkus 3.11.1.
quarkus-container-image-jib

It my understanding as it is mentioned here Jib is the tool which allows me to create the images during build without having the running Docker.
So I have super simple Quarkus-app Hello-World and trying to make the build, previously have these options are added
quarkus.container-image.build=true
quarkus.container-image.name=hello-world-${quarkus.application.name} 

quarkus.container-image.registry=ghcr.io
quarkus.container-image.group=<my github group name>
quarkus.container-image.username=<my github username>
quarkus.container-image.password=<my github token with all required permissions>

and hoping that some container will be the result of my build and will be pushed to Github registry.
But during build I see
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 'docker load' command failed with error: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///Users/me/.docker/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
what certainly tells me that it is needed Docker daemon.
Consequently the push to registry is failed as well.
Thank you.

Hello, did you try enabling jib with quarkus.container.image.builder=jib already ?

hello, yes, I tried, but have ditto.

Did you try setting quarkus.container-image.push to true? See https://quarkus.io/guides/container-image for more info.

Yes, it is part of my application.properties as I have shown this in post

In fact it's not. Please check again what you've pasted to question, and add pom dependencies.

Yes, you are right, thank you, now it works. If you write this as answer, I will vote this. But I have the new one {"errors":[{"code":"BLOB_UPLOAD_INVALID","message":"blob upload invalid"}]} which happens during pushing

@Ladicek found it, I'll let him answer. Please post on separate question for the new error, I'll check it !

When using Jib in Quarkus, Docker is not needed when you push a container image.
When instead you are building it locally, Docker (or Podman) is needed
